# combining mysql queries in a function php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create function that archives a record. I have a list of records with each record having a dropdown with options delete, edit, archive. When archive is clicked Id like that record tp be moved to a new table and then that original record to be removed. Can I have an Insert  and DElete run in the same query? If not  how else can I achieve this? here is what I've currently got:

```
public function archiveCampaign($campaign_id) {

        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `" . DB_PREFIX . "campaigns_archive` SELECT * WHERE campaign_id = '" . (int)$campaign_id . "'");
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "campaigns` WHERE campaign_id = '" . (int)$campaign_id . "'");


        return $campaign_id;
    }
```

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: As far as I know you can't do both INSERT and DELETE with a single SQL statement. I think the closest you'll get is executing them sequentially in a transaction.

Comment: you can; use a multi-query.

Comment: I found a similar query on Stack Exchange, hope this helps https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44215/how-to-combine-delete-and-insert-operations-in-one-statement

Comment: @Don'tPanic why won't a multi-query not work? [as I suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46410863/combining-mysql-queries-in-a-function-php#comment79779547_46410863).

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sure, it could work too, but I wouldn't call that a single SQL statement. ;) And I'd still recommend executing it in a transaction.

Comment: @Don'tPanic True that :-)

Answer (score 0):

## You're already close

Sql doesn't allow multiple commands in a single statement, with the exception of subqueries. Only SELECT statements have an operable return value, thus they are the only commands that can be used in a subquery. That means you will have to run two commands very similar to what you already have written.

If I assume your `db` object's `query` method returns true/false, or something to evaluate (it probably does). Return success/fail, or throw an exception somewhere, so you don't wind up with corrupt data.

```
public function archiveCampaign($campaign_id) {

    $insertResult = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `" . DB_PREFIX . "campaigns_archive` SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "campaigns` WHERE campaign_id = '" . (int)$campaign_id . "'");

    if (!$insertResult) {
        // DON'T DELETE THE DATA, THE INSERT FAILED!
        return false; // or an error object, or throw an exception
    }

    $deleteResult = $this->db->query("DELETE FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "campaigns` WHERE campaign_id = '" . (int)$campaign_id . "'");

    if (!$deleteResult) {
        // DELETE FAILED, remove from archive.
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "campaigns_archive` WHERE campaign_id = '" . (int)$campaign_id . "'");
        return false; // or an error object, or throw an exception
    }

    return true;
}
```

### PHP PDO

Please consider using [PHP:PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php).